# I am trying to pass a value from servlet file to javascript file and i am keep getting null where am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I am trying to pass a value from servlet to js and keep getting null where am i doing it wrong?

login.java-servlet

```
if(bt.equals("frname")){
    String user =request.getParameter("frname");
    String requester=(String) session.getAttribute("uname");
    session.setAttribute("passingv", requester);
    try {
        if (UserDao.validateUser(user)==true) { 
            UserDao.insertvalues(requester,user);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            out.println(" <script type='text/javascript'> ");
            out.println("alert('User doesnot exists');");
            out.println("</script>");
            response.sendRedirect("main.jsp");    
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

main.jsp

```
<%=(String)session.getAttribute("passingv")%>
```

main.js

```
var test = '<%=(String)session.getAttribute("passingv")%>';
console.log(test);
```

Comment: please share the entire error

Comment: its not show error but when i run this is getting printed"<%=(String)request.getAttribute("passingv")%>

Comment: Fixed code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting it in the session but attempting to retrieve it from the request.

Also, if it's an external JS file (e.g., not in the JSP), there's no sense in trying to use a scriptlet in it. You *may* process JS files as JSP files, but this can lead to additional issues. You may want to consider exposing the value in the JSP and retrieving it later from the JS, but there are multiple ways to handle this requirement.

Comment: could you tell me a way to handle this